# How to remove Space between dt and dd in Bootstrap Horizontal description

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know how I can remove the gap/space between dt and dd in bootstrap Horizontal description?

As you can see from following image there is a big space between dt and dd(highlighted in yellow)

[image]

I tried to set the dt cell value by using

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
 width:100px;
 }
.dl-horizontal dd {
 width:100px;
 }
```

but the property just changed the text size! and the cell remained at the same size and position.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```